# how to draw something on a panel by clicking a button

Tags: c#-3.0

i have a panel and a button. i.e:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panel2.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(panel2_Paint);
        panel2.Refresh();
    }
```

and:

```
private void panel2_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {


            Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
            Graphics[,] g1 = new Graphics[140, 140];
            int[,] graph = new int[140, 140];

            int i, j;
            for (i = 0; i < 140; i++)
                for (j = 0; j < 140; j++)
                {
                    graph[i, 8] = 1;
                    graph[i, 10] = 1;
                }

            Pen p = new Pen(Color.Blue);
            SolidBrush mySolidColorBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue);
            Graphics a;
            a = this.CreateGraphics();

            for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
                for (j = 1; j <= 14; j++)
                {
                    g.DrawEllipse(p, 80 * i, 80 * j, 10, 10);
                  g.FillEllipse(mySolidColorBrush, 80 * i, 80 * j, 20, 20);
          a.DrawLine(Pens.Blue, 80 * i, 80 * j, 80 * (i - 1), 80 * (j - 1));
                }

    }
```

when i click the button the output should be displayed on panel but in my case it is displayed on form.

Answer (score -1):

You should create your own user control doing the drawing task.

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void DrawStuff()
    {
        this.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(panel1_Paint);
        this.Refresh();
    }

    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {


        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        Graphics[,] g1 = new Graphics[140, 140];
        int[,] graph = new int[140, 140];

        int i, j;
        for (i = 0; i < 140; i++)
            for (j = 0; j < 140; j++)
            {
                graph[i, 8] = 1;
                graph[i, 10] = 1;
            }

        Pen p = new Pen(Color.Blue);
        SolidBrush mySolidColorBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue);
        Graphics a;
        a = this.CreateGraphics();

        for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            for (j = 1; j <= 14; j++)
            {
                g.DrawEllipse(p, 80 * i, 80 * j, 10, 10);
                g.FillEllipse(mySolidColorBrush, 80 * i, 80 * j, 20, 20);
                a.DrawLine(Pens.Blue, 80 * i, 80 * j, 80 * (i - 1), 80 * (j - 1));
            }

    }
}
```

Then you can just call the public method draw stuff from your parent control.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        userControl11.DrawStuff();
    }
```

[image]

Comment: It is a custom control you can create by your own. Check this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l5L_q_jI494

Comment: userControl11.DrawStuff();    
here usercontrol1 is not an object so it is invalid to call a function using this

Comment: The steps you need to do are: 1. Create a new UserControl (i.e. UserControl1) 2. Add the two methods to the new control 3. Compile your solution 4. Drag the new UserControl1 into your UI 5. Call the Draw method from Button